# To Find Leaders in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Write a program to print all the LEADERS in the array. An element is leader if it is greater than all the elements to its right side. And the rightmost element is always a leader. For example int the array {16, 17, 4, 3, 5, 2}, leaders are 17, 5 and 2.
Let the input array be arr[] and size of the array be size.

o/p what i am getting is 2 5 17

Note: i want o/p in reverse order , also one below other(line break).

```
class LeadersInArray  
{ 
    /* Java Function to print leaders in an array */
    void printLeaders(int arr[], int size) 
    { 
        int max_from_right =  arr[size-1]; 

        /* Rightmost element is always leader */
        System.out.print(max_from_right + " "); 

        for (int i = size-2; i >= 0; i--) 
        { 
            if (max_from_right < arr[i]) 
            {            
            max_from_right = arr[i]; 
            System.out.print(max_from_right + " "); 
            } 
        }     
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    { 
        LeadersInArray lead = new LeadersInArray(); 
        int arr[] = new int[]{16, 17, 4, 3, 5, 2}; 
        int n = arr.length; 
        lead.printLeaders(arr, n); 
    } 
}
```

Expected output:

```
   17
   5
   2
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intead of printing those within the loop, add those to a list, and then print those separately.
Following are the changes in your code.

```
class LeadersInArray {
    List<Integer> printLeaders(int[] arr, int size) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        int max_from_right = arr[size - 1];

        list.add(max_from_right);


        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (max_from_right < arr[i]) {
                max_from_right = arr[i];
                list.add(max_from_right);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LeadersInArray lead = new LeadersInArray();
        int arr[] = new int[]{16, 17, 4, 3, 5, 2};
        List<Integer> integers = lead.printLeaders(arr, arr.length);
        for(int i = integers.size()-1; i>=0 ;i--){
            System.out.println(integers.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```